# I'm trying to follow a beginners tutorial but i'm getting this exit code 1?

Tags: python, excel

Here is my code to import an excel sheet and edit it:

```py
    import openpyxl as xl
    wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlxs')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    cell = sheet['a1']
    cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)
    print(cell.value)
```

However I get the following error message:

```
    C:\Users\mirco\PycharmProjects\pythonProject14\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/mirco/PycharmProjects/pythonProject14/main.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\mirco\PycharmProjects\pythonProject14\main.py", line 2, in <module>
        wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlxs')
      File "C:\Users\mirco\PycharmProjects\pythonProject14\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
        reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
      File "C:\Users\mirco\PycharmProjects\pythonProject14\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
        self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
      File "C:\Users\mirco\PycharmProjects\pythonProject14\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 94, in _validate_archive
        raise InvalidFileException(msg)
    openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .xlxs file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try saving it in one of the supported formats?  It lists four that it supports.

Answer (score -1):

```
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlxs')
```

was supposed to be

```
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
```

a little dyslexic mistake
also had to move excel file to the right location